# Text fade when div reaches the top of the page?

Tags: jquery, fade

I'm creating a site right now with a simple but cool effect. Basically I'm running the backstretch js script that allows the site to have a full background slideshow and it's attached to the "body" of the site. Then I have another simple script that gives the site a margin-top depending on the window size and subtracts the height of the site header so the site header always appears perfectly on the bottom of the screen when the site loads and you can see the full background slideshow.

This is the code I use for the margin-top.

```
$(".site-container").css("margin-top", $(window).height() - $(".site-header").height());
});
```

This works like a charm.

Now the problem I'm having is with the following script I use.

Right below the header I have a div with some text. I'm running a script that makes that text fade out when you scroll down a certain height. I actually set this script up first and I set it to fade out when a user scrolls down 200px which is perfect. When I combine the two they still work but the fade effect is off because it still fades at the same rate. When the page loads, the header starts at the bottom and when the user scrolls up 200px the text is completely faded out. I tried changing it to 800px but all that does is make the text take 800px to completely fade out and that's not what I need. What I need to happen is for this text fade script to trigger when the site header reaches the top of the screen.

Here is the code I'm using to create the text fade.

```
  var didScroll = false;
  var icon = $(".home-sec-1-text");
  var $window = $(window);

  $(window).scroll(function(){
  didScroll = true;
  });

  window.setInterval(function () {
    if (didScroll) {
      if (1-$window.scrollTop()/200 > -10) {
          icon.css({opacity: 1-$window.scrollTop()/200});
      }
      didScroll = false;
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

How can I modify this script to accomplish my goal? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question could be a whole lot shorter

Comment: Hahaha sorry about that. I'm a noob and at the moment I thought all that info would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if I understood you very well but you can handle everything on `scroll()`, and this would be the solution:

```
$(".site-container").css("margin-top", $(window).height() - $(".site-header").height());

var icon = $(".home-sec-1-text");
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function () {
    var windowTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var headerOffset = $(".site-header").offset().top;

    if (windowTop >= headerOffset) {
        icon.fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }
});
```

We are basically comparing the `$(window).scrollTop()` value to the `$(header)` top `offset()` position, so when the scroll reaches the header's top fire the `<div>` fading effect.

See this [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9nwye/).